# How to make this script work, only in mobile devices, not desktop?

Tags: javascript, php, android, mobile, responsive

SOLVED! This script resize Mobile and Desktop screen resolution. How can i make it work, just in Mobile devices, not desktop?

The script makes website responsible, works very well in mobile devices but, Leaves the resolution too large on desktops.

```js
if ( ! class_exists( 'Responsive' ) ) :
class Responsive {

  // Constants
  const NAME = 'responsive';
  const SLUG = 'responsive';

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Constructor makes sure jQuery will be added. //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  function __construct() {

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_jquery' );
    function add_jquery() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_head', array( &$this, 'draw_' ) );

  } // End constructor().

  ///////////////////////////////////
  // Main JavaScript resize script //
  ///////////////////////////////////
  function draw_() {
    ?>
    <script>

      jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        safescale();
      });
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
        jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
      });

      function scale(factor_x){
        jQuery('html').css("transform","scale("+factor_x+","+factor_x+")");
        jQuery('html').css("-moz-transform","scale("+factor_x+","+factor_x+")");
        jQuery('html').css("-webkit-transform","scale("+factor_x+","+factor_x+")");
        jQuery('html').css("-o-transform","scale("+factor_x+","+factor_x+")");
      }

      function safescale(){

        factor_x = jQuery(window).width() / jQuery('body').width() ;

        jQuery("html").css({"position": "absolute", "margin": "0px", "padding": "0px"});
        jQuery("body").css({"position": "absolute", "margin": "0px", "padding": "0px"});
        scale(factor_x);
      }
    </script>

    <?php
    return true;
  }


} // end class
endif;

new Responsive();
```

Comment: Do you know what it's doing or you just copy/pasted from somewhere? Also, what have you tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin to detect mobile only and execute your code only for mobile

http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: I tried it today. but with fatal errors. I don't know how to combine mobile detect code sintax with this responsive script:

<?php 

require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

// Any mobile device (phones or tablets).
if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent executing of js codes for desktop devices just do this :

```
// js :
if (jQuery(window).width() < 1000) {
    // your codes goes here;
}
```

1000px is an example; you can set your desired width;

Comment: Thank You so much! A simple thing, solve my problem! 

What i do:

<script>
      if (jQuery(window).width() < 1080) {
      jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        safescale();
     ...